# Github collaborators in VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

If there are some people who are invited (and accepted) as collaborators for a project on github, how would they go about getting started and set up in VS code? Would they still just clone the repository just like any other repository? And then when they make changes, will they be able to push their changes? How is the authentication handled?

Comment: Git does not do any authentication itself. Git passes this job on to other systems and programs, such as GitHub, ssh, and https. VSCode will have its method of having Git pass the job on to something VSCode can deal with.

Answer (score -1):

They can simply clone, commit and all these things. (Either Git in terminal or in the VSCode gUi itself)
Assuming they have Git on their machine, and they made the SSH keys for GitHub.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).